# Sample source code of the "Hasty Pudding" cipher?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, encryption

I need to use the "Hasty Pudding" cipher because its ability to use a block size of n bits. Some questions in SO mention it but they only point to the Wikipedia article.

AFAIK the cipher is in public domain, but I haven't found any implemmentation source code.

Anyone has seen it?

- [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_Cipher)
- [Specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626185629/http://richard.schroeppel.name:8015/hpc/hpc-spec)

(I'll finally code it in C#, but source code in any language is welcome)

Comment: Look at Rick Schroeppel's home page man! http://richard.schroeppel.name:8015/ftp/hpc/index.html

Comment: The page with working links is this: http://richard.schroeppel.name:8015/hpc/ but none of the links point to source code, only text.

Comment: Did you read the page? "The code for the Hasty Pudding Cipher is freely available in the US and Canada. Send me email with a phone number, the city where you will receive the reply message, and stating your citizenship. I will email you the program. (You get to compile it)."

Comment: Ooops! Didn't read that part, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Seriously, reconsider this decision.  Hasty Pudding has very little research supporting it, which means you really have no idea if it is secure or not.  Plus, as the Wikipedia article says:

> Early in the AES process, David Wagner noted that relatively large classes of Hasty Pudding keys were equivalent in that they led to the same key table.

That's a really bad problem - if keys collide, they can be used to decrypt each other's cipher text.

Instead of worrying about variable cipher block size, fix your input problem.  Lots of options exist, including prefixing the block with a length field and padding out to the cipher block size with random bits.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We just want to use it to obfuscate a transaction number which will be shown as a 4 letters/digits base 41 code/url. 2^21 is inside the range 4^41.  Using a 32 bits cipher and "cycling" looks like will need lots of cycles. HP is the only cipher I found which uses a block smaller than 32 bits. I'll appreciate your comments/alternatives.

Comment: For purely obfuscating, you could write your own 22 bit Feistel cipher.  Just use 32 bit numbers and mask off 10 bits at the appropriate places.

Comment: The problem that David Wagner noted was fixed by Schroeppel. The 'tweak' he added was his solution.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the cipher is in public domain. In fact, I'm wondering that no one pointed you to the source code yet because it's part of the source code that accompanies "Applied Cryptography, Second Edition" by Bruce Schneier.

Keeping it short... at https://www.schneier.com/book-applied-source.html, you will find

> HPC.ZIP
>   Author : Dr. Brian Gladman
>   Date : 14 Jan 99
>   Description: HPC block cipher, candidate for AES.

The download which is available for free via https://www.schneier.com/sccd/HPC.ZIP contains the following sourcecode, which should be exactly what you're looking for…

**std_defs.h**

```
/* 1. Standard types for AES cryptography source code               */

typedef unsigned char   u1byte; /* an 8 bit unsigned character type */
typedef unsigned short  u2byte; /* a 16 bit unsigned integer type   */
typedef unsigned long   u4byte; /* a 32 bit unsigned integer type   */

typedef signed char     s1byte; /* an 8 bit signed character type   */
typedef signed short    s2byte; /* a 16 bit signed integer type     */
typedef signed long     s4byte; /* a 32 bit signed integer type     */

/* 2. Standard interface for AES cryptographic routines             */

/* These are all based on 32 bit unsigned values and will therefore */
/* require endian conversions for big-endian architectures          */

#ifdef  __cplusplus
    extern "C"
    {
#endif

    char **cipher_name(void);
    u4byte *set_key(const u4byte in_key[], const u4byte key_len);
    void encrypt(const u4byte in_blk[4], u4byte out_blk[4]);
    void decrypt(const u4byte in_blk[4], u4byte out_blk[4]);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
    };
#endif

/* 3. Basic macros for speeding up generic operations               */

/* Circular rotate of 32 bit values                                 */

#ifdef _MSC_VER

#  include <stdlib.h>
#  pragma intrinsic(_lrotr,_lrotl)
#  define rotr(x,n) _lrotr(x,n)
#  define rotl(x,n) _lrotl(x,n)

#else

#define rotr(x,n)   (((x) >> ((int)(n))) | ((x) << (32 - (int)(n))))
#define rotl(x,n)   (((x) << ((int)(n))) | ((x) >> (32 - (int)(n))))

#endif

/* Invert byte order in a 32 bit variable                           */

#define bswap(x)    (rotl(x, 8) & 0x00ff00ff | rotr(x, 8) & 0xff00ff00)

/* Extract byte from a 32 bit quantity (little endian notation)     */

#define byte(x,n)   ((u1byte)((x) >> (8 * n)))

/* For inverting byte order in input/output 32 bit words if needed  */

#ifdef  BLOCK_SWAP
#define BYTE_SWAP
#define WORD_SWAP
#endif

#ifdef  BYTE_SWAP
#define io_swap(x)  bswap(x)
#else
#define io_swap(x)  (x)
#endif

/* For inverting the byte order of input/output blocks if needed    */

#ifdef  WORD_SWAP

#define get_block(x)                            \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[0] = io_swap(in_blk[3]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[1] = io_swap(in_blk[2]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[2] = io_swap(in_blk[1]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[3] = io_swap(in_blk[0])

#define put_block(x)                            \
    out_blk[3] = io_swap(((u4byte*)(x))[0]);    \
    out_blk[2] = io_swap(((u4byte*)(x))[1]);    \
    out_blk[1] = io_swap(((u4byte*)(x))[2]);    \
    out_blk[0] = io_swap(((u4byte*)(x))[3])

#define get_key(x,len)                          \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[4] = ((u4byte*)(x))[5] =     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[6] = ((u4byte*)(x))[7] = 0;  \
    switch((((len) + 63) / 64)) {               \
    case 2:                                     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[0] = io_swap(in_key[3]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[1] = io_swap(in_key[2]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[2] = io_swap(in_key[1]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[3] = io_swap(in_key[0]);     \
    break;                                      \
    case 3:                                     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[0] = io_swap(in_key[5]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[1] = io_swap(in_key[4]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[2] = io_swap(in_key[3]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[3] = io_swap(in_key[2]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[4] = io_swap(in_key[1]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[5] = io_swap(in_key[0]);     \
    break;                                      \
    case 4:                                     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[0] = io_swap(in_key[7]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[1] = io_swap(in_key[6]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[2] = io_swap(in_key[5]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[3] = io_swap(in_key[4]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[4] = io_swap(in_key[3]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[5] = io_swap(in_key[2]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[6] = io_swap(in_key[1]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[7] = io_swap(in_key[0]);     \
    }

#else

#define get_block(x)                            \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[0] = io_swap(in_blk[0]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[1] = io_swap(in_blk[1]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[2] = io_swap(in_blk[2]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[3] = io_swap(in_blk[3])

#define put_block(x)                            \
    out_blk[0] = io_swap(((u4byte*)(x))[0]);    \
    out_blk[1] = io_swap(((u4byte*)(x))[1]);    \
    out_blk[2] = io_swap(((u4byte*)(x))[2]);    \
    out_blk[3] = io_swap(((u4byte*)(x))[3])

#define get_key(x,len)                          \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[4] = ((u4byte*)(x))[5] =     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[6] = ((u4byte*)(x))[7] = 0;  \
    switch((((len) + 63) / 64)) {               \
    case 4:                                     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[6] = io_swap(in_key[6]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[7] = io_swap(in_key[7]);     \
    case 3:                                     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[4] = io_swap(in_key[4]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[5] = io_swap(in_key[5]);     \
    case 2:                                     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[0] = io_swap(in_key[0]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[1] = io_swap(in_key[1]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[2] = io_swap(in_key[2]);     \
    ((u4byte*)(x))[3] = io_swap(in_key[3]);     \
    }

#endif
```

**hpc.c**

```
/* This is an independent implementation of the encryption algorithm:   */

/*                                                                      */
/*         HPC-128 by Richard Schroeppel                                */
/*                                                                      */
/* which is a candidate algorithm in the Advanced Encryption Standard   */
/* programme of the US National Institute of Standards and Technology.  */
/*                                                                      */
/* Copyright in this implementation is held by Dr B R Gladman but I     */
/* hereby give permission for its free direct or derivative use subject */
/* to acknowledgment of its origin and compliance with any conditions   */
/* that the originators of the algorithm place on its exploitation.     */
/*                                                                      */
/* Dr Brian Gladman (gladman@seven77.demon.co.uk) 14th January 1999     */

/* Timing data for HPC (hpc.c)

Core timing without I/O endian conversion:

128 bit key:
Key Setup:  120749 cycles
Encrypt:      1429 cycles =    17.9 mbits/sec
Decrypt:      1599 cycles =    16.0 mbits/sec
Mean:         1514 cycles =    16.9 mbits/sec

192 bit key:
Key Setup:  120754 cycles
Encrypt:      1477 cycles =    17.3 mbits/sec
Decrypt:      1599 cycles =    16.0 mbits/sec
Mean:         1538 cycles =    16.6 mbits/sec

256 bit key:
Key Setup:  120731 cycles
Encrypt:      1462 cycles =    17.5 mbits/sec
Decrypt:      1590 cycles =    16.1 mbits/sec
Mean:         1526 cycles =    16.8 mbits/sec

Full timing with I/O endian conversion:

128 bit key:
Key Setup:  118606 cycles
Encrypt:      1479 cycles =    17.3 mbits/sec
Decrypt:      1599 cycles =    16.0 mbits/sec
Mean:         1539 cycles =    16.6 mbits/sec

192 bit key:
Key Setup:  118538 cycles
Encrypt:      1480 cycles =    17.3 mbits/sec
Decrypt:      1583 cycles =    16.2 mbits/sec
Mean:         1532 cycles =    16.7 mbits/sec

256 bit key:
Key Setup:  118532 cycles
Encrypt:      1465 cycles =    17.5 mbits/sec
Decrypt:      1599 cycles =    16.0 mbits/sec
Mean:         1532 cycles =    16.7 mbits/sec

*/

#define BYTE_SWAP

#ifdef CORE_TIME
#  undef BYTE_SWAP
#endif

#include "../std_defs.h"

static char *alg_name[] = { "hpc", "hpc.c", "hpc" };

char **cipher_name()
{
return alg_name;
}

typedef u4byte  u8byte[2];

u8byte  l_key[286];
u8byte  spice[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

u8byte  p119 = { 0xa23249d6, 0x2b992ddf };
u8byte  e19  = { 0xc0b36173, 0x25b946eb };
u8byte  r220 = { 0xe9e17158, 0xc442f56b };

#define xor_eq(x,y)     (x)[0] ^= (y)[0]; (x)[1] ^= (y)[1]
#define and_eq(x,y)     (x)[0] &= (y)[0]; (x)[1] &= (y)[1]
#define  or_eq(x,y)     (x)[0] |= (y)[0]; (x)[1] |= (y)[1]

#define add_eq(x,y)     (x)[1] += (y)[1] + (((x)[0] += (y)[0]) < (y)[0] ? 1 : 0)
#define sub_eq(x,y)     xs = (x)[0]; (x)[1] -= (y)[1] + (((x)[0] -= (y)[0]) > xs ? 1 : 0)

#define lsh_eq(x,n)                                         \
if((n) > 31)                                            \
{   (x)[1] = (x)[0] << ((n) & 31); (x)[0] = 0;          \
}                                                       \
else if((n) > 0)                                        \
{   (x)[1] = ((x)[1] << (n)) | ((x)[0] >> (-(n) & 31)); \
    (x)[0] = (x)[0] << (n);                             \
}

#define rsh_eq(x,n)                                         \
if((n) > 31)                                            \
{   (x)[0] = (x)[1] >> ((n) & 31); (x)[1] = 0;          \
}                                                       \
else if((n) > 0)                                        \
{   (x)[0] = ((x)[0] >> (n)) | ((x)[1] << (-(n) & 31)); \
    (x)[1] = (x)[1] >> (n);                             \
}

#define lo(x)   ((x) & 0x0000ffff)
#define hi(x)   ((x) >> 16)

void mult_64(u8byte r, const u8byte x, const u8byte y)
{   u4byte  x0, x1, x2, x3, y0, y1, y2, y3, t0, t1, t2, t3, c;

x0 = lo(x[0]); x1 = hi(x[0]); x2 = lo(x[1]); x3 = hi(x[1]);
y0 = lo(y[0]); y1 = hi(y[0]); y2 = lo(y[1]); y3 = hi(y[1]);

t0 = x0 * y0; r[0] = lo(t0); c = hi(t0);

t0 = x0 * y1; t1 = x1 * y0; c += lo(t0) + lo(t1);
r[0] += (c << 16); c = hi(c) + hi(t0) + hi(t1);

t0 = x0 * y2; t1 = x1 * y1; t2 = x2 * y0;
c += lo(t0) + lo(t1) + lo(t2); r[1] = lo(c);
c = hi(c) + hi(t0) + hi(t1) + hi(t2);

t0 = x0 * y3; t1 = x1 * y2; t2 = x2 * y1; t3 = x3 * y0;
c += lo(t0) + lo(t1) + lo(t2) + lo(t3); r[1] += (c << 16);
/*
c = hi(c) + hi(t0) + hi(t1) + hi(t2) + hi(t3);

t0 = x1 * y3; t1 = x2 * y2; t2 = x3 * y1;
c += lo(t0) + lo(t1) + lo(t2); r[1][0] = lo(c);
c = hi(c) + hi(t0) + hi(t1) + hi(t2);

t0 = x2 * y3; t1 = x3 * y2; c += lo(t0) + lo(t1);
r[1][0] += (c << 16); c = hi(c) + hi(t0) + hi(t1);

r[1][1] = c + x3 * y3;
*/
};

u8byte  l_key[286]; /* storage for the key schedule         */

/* initialise the key schedule from the user supplied key   */

u4byte *set_key(const u4byte in_key[], const u4byte key_len)
{   u8byte  s[8], t;
u4byte  i, j, xs;

l_key[0][0] = p119[0] + 3; l_key[0][1] = p119[1];
t[0] = key_len; t[1] = 0; mult_64(l_key[1], e19, t);
l_key[2][0] = (r220[0] << 3) | (r220[1] >> 29);
l_key[2][1] = (r220[1] << 3) | (r220[0] >> 29);

for(i = 3; i < 256; ++i)
{
    t[0] = l_key[i - 3][0]; t[1] = l_key[i - 3][1]; lsh_eq(t, 41);
    l_key[i][0] = l_key[i - 3][0]; l_key[i][1] = l_key[i - 3][1];
    rsh_eq(l_key[i], 23);
    or_eq(l_key[i], t);
    xor_eq(l_key[i], l_key[i - 2]);
    add_eq(l_key[i], l_key[i - 1]);
}

l_key[0][1] ^= io_swap(in_key[0]); l_key[0][0] ^= io_swap(in_key[1]);
l_key[1][1] ^= io_swap(in_key[2]); l_key[1][0] ^= io_swap(in_key[3]);

if(key_len > 128)
{
    l_key[2][1] ^= io_swap(in_key[4]); l_key[2][0] ^= io_swap(in_key[5]);
}

if(key_len > 192)
{
    l_key[3][1] ^= io_swap(in_key[6]); l_key[3][0] ^= io_swap(in_key[7]);
}

for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    s[i][0] = l_key[248 + i][0]; s[i][1] = l_key[248 + i][1];
}

for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    for(i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        t[0] = l_key[i][0]; t[1] = l_key[i][1]; xor_eq(t, l_key[(i + 83) & 255]);
        add_eq(t, l_key[s[0][0] & 255]);
        xor_eq(s[0], t); add_eq(s[1], s[0]); xor_eq(s[3], s[2]);
        sub_eq(s[5], s[4]); xor_eq(s[7], s[6]);
        t[0] = s[0][0]; t[1] = s[0][1]; rsh_eq(t, 13); add_eq(s[3], t);
        t[0] = s[1][0]; t[1] = s[1][1]; lsh_eq(t, 11); xor_eq(s[4], t);
        t[0] = s[3][0]; t[1] = s[3][1];
        lsh_eq(t, s[1][0] & 31);
        xor_eq(s[5], t);
        t[0] = s[2][0]; t[1] = s[2][1]; rsh_eq(t, 17); add_eq(s[6], t);
        t[0] = s[3][0]; t[1] = s[3][1]; add_eq(t, s[4]); or_eq(s[7], t);
        sub_eq(s[2], s[5]);
        t[0] = s[6][0] ^ i; t[1] = s[6][1]; sub_eq(s[0], t);
        t[0] = s[5][0]; t[1] = s[5][1]; add_eq(t, p119); xor_eq(s[1], t);
        t[0] = s[7][0]; t[1] = s[7][1]; rsh_eq(t, j); add_eq(s[2], t);
        xor_eq(s[2], s[1]); sub_eq(s[4], s[3]);
        xor_eq(s[6], s[5]); add_eq(s[0], s[7]);
        l_key[i][0] = s[2][0]; l_key[i][1] = s[2][1]; add_eq(l_key[i], s[6]);
    }

for(i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
    l_key[256 + i][0] = l_key[i][0]; l_key[256 + i][1] = l_key[i][1];
}

return (u4byte*)l_key;
};

/* encrypt a block of text  */
void encrypt(const u4byte in_blk[4], u4byte out_blk[4])
{
u8byte  s0, s1, k, kk, t;
u4byte  tt, xs;
s4byte  i;
s0[1] = io_swap(in_blk[0]); s0[0] = io_swap(in_blk[1]);
s1[1] = io_swap(in_blk[2]); s1[0] = io_swap(in_blk[3]);
add_eq(s0, l_key[128]); add_eq(s1, l_key[129]);
for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    tt = s0[0] & 255; k[0] = l_key[tt][0]; k[1] = l_key[tt][1];
    add_eq(s1, k);  lsh_eq(k, 8); xor_eq(s0, k); xor_eq(s1, s0);
    t[0] = s1[0]; t[1] = s1[1]; rsh_eq(t, 11); sub_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = s1[0]; t[1] = s1[1]; lsh_eq(t, 2); xor_eq(s0, t);
    sub_eq(s0, spice[i ^ 4]);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; lsh_eq(t, 32);
    kk[0] = p119[0] + 128; kk[1] = p119[1]; xor_eq(t, kk); add_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; rsh_eq(t, 17); xor_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; rsh_eq(t, 34); xor_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = spice[i][0]; t[1] = spice[i][1]; xor_eq(s0, t);
    lsh_eq(t, 5); add_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = spice[i][0]; t[1] = spice[i][1]; rsh_eq(t, 4);
    add_eq(s1, t); xor_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; lsh_eq(t, 22 + (s0[0] & 31)); add_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; rsh_eq(t, 23); xor_eq(s0, t);
    sub_eq(s0, spice[i ^ 7]);
    tt = s0[0] & 255; k[0] = l_key[tt][0]; k[1] = l_key[tt][1];
    tt += 3 * i + 1; kk[0] = l_key[tt][0]; kk[1] = l_key[tt][1];
    xor_eq(s1, k); t[0] = kk[0]; t[1] = kk[1]; lsh_eq(t, 8);
    xor_eq(s0, t); xor_eq(kk, k);
    t[0] = kk[0]; t[1] = kk[1]; rsh_eq(t, 5); add_eq(s1, t);
    t[0] = kk[0]; t[1] = kk[1]; lsh_eq(t, 12); sub_eq(s0, t);
    kk[0] &= ~255; xor_eq(s0, kk);  add_eq(s1, s0);
    t[0] = s1[0]; t[1] = s1[1]; lsh_eq(t, 3); add_eq(s0, t);
    xor_eq(s0, spice[i ^ 2]); add_eq(s0, l_key[144 + i]);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; lsh_eq(t, 22); add_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = s1[0]; t[1] = s1[1]; rsh_eq(t, 4); xor_eq(s0, t);
    add_eq(s0, spice[i ^ 1]);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; rsh_eq(t, 33 + i); xor_eq(s0, t);
}
add_eq(s0, l_key[136]); add_eq(s1, l_key[137]);
out_blk[0] = io_swap(s0[1]); out_blk[1] = io_swap(s0[0]);
out_blk[2] = io_swap(s1[1]); out_blk[3] = io_swap(s1[0]);
};
/* decrypt a block of text  */
void decrypt(const u4byte in_blk[4], u4byte out_blk[4])
{
u8byte  s0, s1, k, kk, t;
u4byte  tt, xs;
s4byte  i;
s0[1] = io_swap(in_blk[0]); s0[0] = io_swap(in_blk[1]);
s1[1] = io_swap(in_blk[2]); s1[0] = io_swap(in_blk[3]);
sub_eq(s0, l_key[136]); sub_eq(s1, l_key[137]);
for(i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
{
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; rsh_eq(t, 33 + i); xor_eq(s0, t);
    sub_eq(s0, spice[i ^ 1]);
    t[0] = s1[0]; t[1] = s1[1]; rsh_eq(t, 4); xor_eq(s0, t);
    k[0] = s0[0]; k[1] = s0[1]; lsh_eq(k, 22);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; sub_eq(t, k);
    lsh_eq(t, 22); sub_eq(s0, t); sub_eq(s0, l_key[144 + i]);
    xor_eq(s0, spice[i ^ 2]); t[0] = s1[0]; t[1] = s1[1]; lsh_eq(t, 3);
    sub_eq(s0, t); sub_eq(s1, s0);
    tt = s0[0] & 255; k[0] = l_key[tt][0]; k[1] = l_key[tt][1];
    tt += 3 * i + 1; kk[0] = l_key[tt][0]; kk[1] = l_key[tt][1]; xor_eq(kk, k);
    t[0] = kk[0] & ~255; t[1] = kk[1]; xor_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = kk[0]; t[1] = kk[1]; lsh_eq(t, 12); add_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = kk[0]; t[1] = kk[1]; rsh_eq(t, 5); sub_eq(s1, t);
    kk[0] = l_key[tt][0]; kk[1] = l_key[tt][1]; lsh_eq(kk, 8);
    xor_eq(s0, kk); xor_eq(s1, k); add_eq(s0, spice[i ^ 7]);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; rsh_eq(t, 23); xor_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; rsh_eq(t, 46); xor_eq(s0, t);
    tt = 22 + (s0[0] & 31); t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; lsh_eq(t, tt);
    kk[0] = s0[0]; kk[1] = s0[1]; sub_eq(kk, t); lsh_eq(kk, tt); sub_eq(s0, kk);
    t[0] = kk[0] = spice[i][0]; t[1] = kk[1] = spice[i][1]; rsh_eq(kk, 4);
    xor_eq(s0, kk); sub_eq(s1, kk); k[0] = t[0]; k[1] = t[1]; lsh_eq(k, 5);
    sub_eq(s0, k); xor_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = s0[0]; t[1] = s0[1]; rsh_eq(t, 17); xor_eq(s0, t);
    t[0] = p119[0] + 128; t[1] = p119[1]; k[0] = s0[0]; k[1] = s0[1];
    sub_eq(k, t); lsh_eq(k, 32); xor_eq(t, k); sub_eq(s0, t);
    add_eq(s0, spice[i ^ 4]); t[0] = s1[0]; t[1] = s1[1]; lsh_eq(t, 2);
    xor_eq(s0, t); t[0] = s1[0]; t[1] = s1[1]; rsh_eq(t, 11); add_eq(s0, t);
    xor_eq(s1, s0); tt = s0[0] & 255; k[0] = l_key[tt][0]; k[1] = l_key[tt][1];
    t[0] = k[0]; t[1] = k[1]; lsh_eq(t, 8); xor_eq(s0, t); sub_eq(s1, k);
}
sub_eq(s0, l_key[128]); sub_eq(s1, l_key[129]);
out_blk[0] = io_swap(s0[1]); out_blk[1] = io_swap(s0[0]);
out_blk[2] = io_swap(s1[1]); out_blk[3] = io_swap(s1[0]);
};
```